# Proving $a+b \leq 1 + ab$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

This may be stupid but somehow I do not see how to prove this.

> Let $0 \leq a,b \leq 1$. Then $$a + b \leq 1 + ab$$

Has someone a hint?

Comment: $(a-1)(b-1)=ab+1-(a+b)\geq 0\implies ab+1\geq a+b$

Comment: @Sophie You should write this up as an answer, it should be accepted as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint*: Consider $(1-a)(1-b)$. What can you say about its sign?

Comment: It should be positive.

Comment: Exactly, or at least non-negative. Can you finish it from there?

Comment: Yes, thank you! So obvious now.